# Grid columns and rows failing to align properly

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'm new to CSS and i have been trying to construct a quite simple layout with CSS grid .

I drew a sketch:

[image]

So after reading the **Great explanation** in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), i started writing the code  but for some reason the rows aren't laid correctly as i would expect (my code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Codingforpleasure/pen/rRaqML)).

```
grid-template-rows: 5em 50vh 100vh 30vh;
grid-template-columns: 0.15% 0.3% 0.4 0.15%;

grid-template-areas: "logo search-bar menu . "
                        "description description description nav-bar"
                        "main main main . "
                        "footer footer footer footer";
```

Can someone please explain and assist me how to do it correctly?

Thank you all in advance, 
for the help.

Comment: The link is not working, you need to remove the `\`` around it. Also you will need to provide code on stackoverflow as well otherwise the editor won't allow just a link to code.

Comment: Thank you, fixed the issue you mentioned!

Comment: `grid-template-columns: 0.15% 0.3% 0.4 0.15%;` missing a unit after `0.4` .. and  don't you think they are small value? the total need to be 100% not 1%

Comment: Thank you oops my bad, fixed it to: 
grid-template-columns: 15% 30% 40% 15%;
but still how come "navigation-links" (icons) is not located in the correct place (as mentioned in the sketch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, you're missing a percentage unit in a column value:

```
grid-template-columns: 0.15% 0.3% 0.4 0.15%
```

That invalidates the entire rule.

**Second**, [`grid-area` property values don't use quotes](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-area-concept).

This is invalid: `grid-area: "logo"`.

It's just `grid-area: logo`.

**Third**, your navigation links are out of place because you have an HTML-CSS mismatch:

```
<nav class="navigation-icon-links">navigation-links</nav>

.navigation-links {
    grid-area: nav-bar;
    background:orange;
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WmbYOp)